# Pure CSS equal height columns with border-bottom on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was hoping you could help me find a solution to a problem I'm having after trying out [Matthew James Taylor's equal height columns](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks) using pure css.

I'm trying to add a `border-bottom` to a column when hovered over by the user (**see image: 1**). The problem I'm having is that as these `DIV`'s are nested the borders seem to stack on top of eachother (**see image: 3**). I'm trying to have all the borders on an even level as the effect I'm going for would have them overlap with the gray line

Furthermore, the grey horizontal line in the image would stretch to 100% width of the page and would be on an even level with the black `border-bottom`. When not hovering over any of the titles (hi there!, contact, twitter) I'd like the columns with content to slide up until only the titles are visible, this would be the only thing I'd like to use Javascript. Perhaps all of this isn't possible using just CSS, or maybe there's a better way of doing it?

[image: Image showing my problem]**

Comment: Difficult to follow, even after looking at the images. Can you create a simple example in jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Thanks for the response, http://jsfiddle.net/cbGG7/ shows the stacked border problem (due to DIV's being nested). I'm trying to recreate the top design which can be seen in the image I have included in my original post. I was hoping to achieve this using the equal heights column tutorial, but maybe there's a better way to recreate it?

Comment: If you are trying to get a hover border for col3, then thy is your hover for the div container3 rather than for the div col3?

Comment: I tried adding the `border-bottom` to `#col3` but that positioned the border at the end of content instead of at the bottom of the column. This would break the overlapping effect I'm trying to get to work. Thank you for the help though Matt, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this would be solved far more easily with `display: table` than the CSS trickery you are currently using.

http://jsfiddle.net/rrPKA/

```
#container { display: table; }
.row { display: table-row; }
.row > div { 
    display: table-cell; 
    width: 100px; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.row > div:hover { border-bottom: 1px solid gray; }
```

Comment: Great stuff, many thanks, but unfortunately it breaks in IE7 and below. However, it functions exactly as I had in mind. Is there a way to make it degrade gracefully in IE7 and below?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so. You may want to look at your server logs to see how many IE7/6 users you have. Just last week MS announced they are autoupdating all IE7 and below browsers to 8 or 9 as of January with a goal < 1% IE6 users. I assume IE7 should be close to the same. My conservative company finally agreed to drop IE6/7 this year as well. http://www.anandtech.com/show/5248/microsoft-launches-ie6-countdown-site-will-begin-automatic-ie-upgrades-for-users

Comment: According to these stats IE7 is down to about 3.4% and if forced updates work as planned I would expect this to be around 1% by midyear 2012. http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: I've marked your answer as the solution. Excellent added information too, many thanks and happy holidays!